# Android: How to add text to png format image?

Tags: android, textview, png

I have the following png image:

[image]

Is it possible for us programmatically adding the text within the dialog image while not damage its transparency?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Is `FrameLayout` an option? If it is, you could use a `TextView` on top of this `ImageView`.

Comment: You could set the Background of the TextView with your image. If it's a png, it won't mess up with your transparency.

Comment: In fact, you could turn that into a nine-patch and then it would adapt to your view size.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, and i am try to use the 9-patch image to achieve my goal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. You must have an 9patch png like the following

[image]

Add this line to your textview. You'll use the image as the textview backgound

```
        android:background="@drawable/tex_bulle_dialogue"
```